# Apache redirect to parent folder

Tags: apache-2.2, redirection, rewritecond

I have a server pointing to
     `DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite`

I would like to redirect all requests from
    `/var/www/mysite/folder/`
to 
     `/var/www/mysite/`

I tried the following:

```
 `RedirectMatch 301 /mysite/folder/(.*) http://example.com/folder/$1`
```

But it doesn't work.

After spending several hours on it, I can't find where is the problem.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is your complete Apache configuration?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is [unanswerable/caused by something singular/useless to the community at large](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6196/118258).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove /mysite from the redirect-match. The redirect-match is relative to the document root.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /folder/(.*) http://example.com/folder/$1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RedirectPermanent /folder/ http://example.com/
```